# IPython Notebook in a virtualenv, using Python 3.3

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, virtualenv, ipython

I have my Ubuntu 12.04 system set up so that I can create a virtualenv with either Python 2.7 or Python 3.3, and run IPython Notebook. The problem is, I don't know exactly what I did to my system to make this possible. I am trying to help someone else get their system set up the same way, and I'm not sure what packages I am missing.

On my system I can run the following commands to get IPython Notebook running in a virtualenv:

```
~$ mkdir test_ipython3.3
~$ cd test_ipython3.3
~/test_ipython3.3$ virtualenv -p python3.3 venv
~/test_ipython3.3$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)~/test_ipython3.3$ pip install ipython[all]==1.1.0
```

I can do the same set of commands with `virtualenv -p python2.7 venv`, and have an almost identical environment except it runs Python 2.7.

I am trying to get a 12.04 installation on virtualbox set up so that I can run these commands successfully as well, but I keep failing. After building a clean Ubuntu 12.04 machine in virtualbox, I do the following:

```
# Update machine:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

# Install Python 3.3:
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install python3.3

# Install virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install pip --upgrade
sudo pip install virtualenv

# Install necessary packages:
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3.3-dev libzmq-dev

# Build a venv, using Python 2.7, which works:
~$ mkdir test_ipython2.7
~$ cd test_ipython2.7
~/test_ipython2.7$ virtualenv -p python2.7 venv
~/test_ipython2.7$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)~/test_ipython2.7$ pip install ipython[all]==1.1.0
(venv)~/test_ipython2.7$ ipython notebook
# Works, opening an ipynb that runs Python 3.3

# Build a venv, using Python 3.3, which fails:
~$ mkdir test_ipython3.3
~$ cd test_ipython3.3
~/test_ipython3.3$ virtualenv -p python3.3 venv
~/test_ipython3.3$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)~/test_ipython3.3$ pip install ipython[all]==1.1.0
(venv)~/test_ipython3.3$ ipython notebook
# Fails, says that ipython is not installed, despite having reported otherwise
```

After trying to install ipython in the 3.3 virtualenv, I get a message that ipython and a number of supporting packages have been installed successfully. But when I try to run ipython or ipython notebook, I get a message that ipython is not installed. Watching the install process, and scrolling back through the output, I can't find any obvious failures. I even installed zmq from source, so I have zmq 4.0.3 installed, which ipython is finding during its installation.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: what do you get from `which ipython` and `which pip` at various points? Make sure these are inside the envs.

Comment: `which pip` shows that pip is inside the venv (`test_ipython3.3/venv/bin/pip`), and `which ipython` has no output because ipython never really gets installed.

Comment: Also, I tried using easy_install to install ipython within the venv. The installation docs for ipython say that easy_install will probably work better than pip. I got the same results with easy_install, within the venv.

Comment: what is the output of the `pip install` call that is failing?

Comment: The output of `pip install ipython[all]==1.1.0`, from an active virtualenv: http://pastebin.com/37cfN4HJ

Comment: ah, silly me. IPython entry points get a `3` suffix when installed with Python 3, so it would be `ipython3 notebook`. Looks like your install is all working from that output.

Comment: You're right! That was really simple. I'm still quite curious about the best way to install ipython when you want access to a 2.7 interpreter sometimes, and a 3.3 interpreter other times.

Comment: If you want to write a quick answer about using the command `ipython3 notebook` instead of `ipython notebook`, I'll be happy to accept it. Otherwise, I'll answer my own question in a couple days for the record. Thank you very much, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IPython 1.x creates scripts with a '3' suffix when installed with Python 3, to avoid conflict with IPython installed with Python 2, so the command you want is:

```
ipython3 notebook
```

In current development IPython (will be 2.0), this behavior is changed somewhat, where IPython installs both the non-suffix and the suffix entry points (`ipython` and `ipython3` on Python 3, `ipython` and `ipython2` on Python 2), following the pattern established by other packages, such as nose.

> I'm still quite curious about the best way to install ipython when you want access to a 2.7 interpreter sometimes, and a 3.3 interpreter other times.

There are two ways to deal with this:

The first is to create an `ipython` script somewhere very high priority in your PATH (I use `~/bin`),
with the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```

This will use the current python on your PATH, no matter what, so when you activate a Python 3 env, ipython will use that, etc.

The second is to just use:

```
python -m IPython
```

or

```
python3 -m IPython
```

which is the same as typing `ipython`, but you are specifying the interpreter to use explicitly, so there can be no doubt about what Python is in use.

Answer (score -2):

These problems seem to be solved at: http://ihrke.github.io/jupyter.html

Comment: Place the relevant information from the URL instead of pasting the URL: Answers should be as much self contained as possible to be considered a good answer.